# What is the correct way to handle IUnknown Reference count with multiple interfaces in type library?

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop, iunknown

I have C# Type Library that has multiple interfaces defined. This outputs to a single .tlb file – called BACnetLib.tlb

First is an interface for HTTP communications.

```
namespace WebServiceLib
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("XXX")]    
    public interface ICxWebServiceLibEvents
    {
        void COM_REPLY_GET_Success(int id, uint errorCode);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("YYY")]
    public interface ICxWebServiceLib
    {

        void COM_REQUEST_GetJSONObject([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int id,
                                            ICxWebServiceLibEvents callbackClient);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("ZZZ")]
    public class CxWebServiceLib : ICxWebServiceLib
    {

        void ICxWebServiceLib.COM_REQUEST_GetJSONObject(int id, ICxWebServiceLibEvents callbackClient)
        {
            // implementation
            // ...
            callbackClient.COM_REPLY_GET_Success(id, errorCode);
        }
     }
}
```

Another is an interface to handle BACnet communications:

```
namespace BACnetLib
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("AAA")]
    public interface IBACnetLibEvents
    {
        void COM_REPLY_Finished_Task(int id, int nErrorCode);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("BBB")]
    public interface IBACnetLib
    {
        void COM_REQUEST_ReadProperty([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int id, IBAC-netLibEvents CallbackClient,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4))
    }


    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), Guid("CCC")]
    public class BACnetLib : IBACnetLib
    {
        public void COM_REQUEST_ReadProperty([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int id, IBACnetLibEvents CallbackClien)
        {
            // Implementation
            // ....
            CallbackClient.COM_REPLY_Finished_Task(id, nErrorCode);
        }
    }

);
```

This .tlb is imported in a separate C++ application. The WebServiceLibEvents and BACnetLibEvents interfaces have separate implementations.

C++ Web Service handler:

```
#import "..\\lib\\BACnetLib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, named_guids, no_namespace

class CWebServiceObject : ICxWebServiceLibEvents
{
private:
    ICxWebServiceLibPtr m_webServer;
    DWORD m_refCount = 1;

public:
    CWebServiceObject()
    {
        const auto hr = m_webServer.CreateInstance(__uuidof(CxWebServiceLib));
        if (FAILED(hr)) 
        { 
            throw exception 
        }
    }

    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID&, void**) override
    {
        if (iid == __uuidof(ICxWebServiceLibEvents) || iid == __uuidof(IUnknown))
        {
            *pp = this;
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) override 
    { 
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_refCount); 
    }

    ULONG __stdcall Release(void) override
    {
        return InterlockedDecrement(&m_refCount);
    }

    HRESULT __stdcall COM_REPLY_GET_Success(long id, unsigned long errorCode) over-ride;
    {
        // handle reply
    }
}
```

C++ BACnet Comms Object:

```
#import "..\\lib\\BACnetLib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, named_guids, no_namespace

class CCommsObject : public IBACnetLibEvents
{
private:
    IBACnetLibPtr m_server;
    DWORD m_refCount = 1;

public:
    CCommsObject()
    {
        auto hr = m_server.CreateInstance(__uuidof(BACnetLib));
        if (FAILED(hr)) 
        { 
            throw exception
        }
    }


    HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID &, void **) override
    {
        if (iid == __uuidof(IBACnetLibEvents) || iid == __uuidof(IUnknown))
        {
            *pp = this;
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
    ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) override 
    {  
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_refCount); 
    }
    ULONG __stdcall Release(void) override
    {
        return InterlockedDecrement(&m_refCount);
    }

    
    HRESULT __stdcall COM_REPLY_Finished_Task(long id, long nErrorCode) override
    {
        // handle reply
    }
}
```

I create instances of these in my C++ app using unique_ptrs, and once created they're valid for the lifetime of of the application.

However, On shutdown I get an access violation in clr.dll:
[image: stack trace when Access Violation is thrown]

I'm not sure exactly how to debug this properly. I believe it might be because I'm not handling the reference count correctly or something like that.

Another issue is if I create another, shorter lived instance of one of these objects in my C++ application, it can cause a crash when calling the other.

1. Is there something wrong with this design of defining multiple interfaces in a single type library?
2. Am I handling the reference counting correctly?

Comment: `*pp = this;` is not good, among other issues. You have a good example on how to implement a COM object here: https://jackmin.home.blog/2019/01/11/com-tutorial/ However, you can also use Microsoft's tooling such as ATL from Visual Studio. Do you have a full reproducing project? How you call all this is important too. Rpcrt4 in the stack means some cross threads calls likely happen, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier No, this is part of a much larger project. I haven't narrowed it down to a smaller reproducible project. But thanks for the link, it contains useful information on the implementation. I see using static cast is probably better than *pp = this so will update my code accordingly. The reference count and access violation issue is fixed with the suggestion to use CComPtr below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the program, the unique_ptrs are destroyed (freeing the memory) and then the COM cleanup is called.

This cleanup will call `Release` on any interface pointers still held, including your `CWebServiceObject` and/or `CCommsObject` objects. But these objects have already been destroyed and their memory freed, leading to an access violation.

You need to free the memory when `Release` is actually called:

```cpp
    ULONG __stdcall AddRef(void) override 
    {  
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_refCount); 
    }
    ULONG __stdcall Release(void) override
    {
        auto refCount = InterlockedDecrement(&m_refCount);
        if (refCount == 0) {
            delete this;
        }
        return refCount;
    }
```

And since the object's life is now managed with the IUnknown interface, you can't use `unique_ptr` anymore. It can be replaced with `CComPtr`:

```cpp
// auto webServiceObject = std::make_unique<CWebServiceObject>();

// -> Will call `Release` when destroyed instead of `delete`
CComPtr<CWebServiceObject> webServiceObject(new CWebServiceObject());
```

(You need to change the refCount to be initialized to 0 instead as `CComPtr`'s constructor calls `AddRef`)

Comment: Thanks Artyer. Simply adding the "delete this" to the Release() function still has the same issue when using the unique_ptr - the memory is freed before the cleanup can call Release on the objects. 

I think using the raw pointer is the way to go as it stops the access violation on shutdown. Even though using new without a corresponding delete goes against my instincts as a programmer because when I do this, it doesn't get to the delete in Release while debugging.

Comment: @ChrisJ On second thought, leaking an `IUnknown` might be a bad idea if the base class has some resources that need to be flushed or something. Edited to use a different smart pointer instead.

Comment: CComPtr is the way to go. I can see the memory being deleted on shutdown on shutdown and prevents the access violation. Thanks for your help